# Recycle View scrolls slow . How to fix it?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I just implemented expandable layout in recycle view .[ExpandableLayout library](https://github.com/SilenceDut/ExpandableLayout)

> **Issue : Recycle view scroll slow at first time . expand/collpase working good but list scroll slow**
>
> **NOTE :**  ***Its working smoothly on `4 GB RAM` Device but laggy scroll on `2 GB RAM` Device . I tested with  Moto g3 (2 GB RAM) and Moto
>   g5 Plus (4 GB RAM)***

Data coming from web-service and passing array-list through adapter.

Layout row file (XML) in **Nested Linear Layouts.** (may be its viewgroups load but i also tried with Constraint layout .Still recycleview load laggy)

I am replacing view during expansion and collapse item view (I already commented that code. but still my recycle view is slow )
There is no use of any image storing in itemview .
Already tried `setHasFixedSize` , `notifyDataChanged` , `setCache` , `adapter.setHasStableIds(true);`

but still recycleview loads laggy at first time only .

Help me to fix this issue. I am still finding the issue !
You can check my Adapter Code!

```
public class PendingOrdersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PendingOrdersAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public LayoutInflater mInflater;
public HashSet<Integer> mExpandedPositionSet = new HashSet<>();
Context context;
ArrayList<CustomerDetails> list;
CustomerDetails details;


public PendingOrdersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CustomerDetails> list) {
this.context = context;
this.list = list;
this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
View item = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.pending_order_item, parent, false);
return new ViewHolder(item);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
 details = list.get(position);

holder.updateItem(position, holder);
holder.tvOrderNo.setText("" + details.getOrderID());
holder.tvCustomerName.setText("" + details.getCustomerName());
holder.tvTotalPrice.setText("" + details.getTotalPrice());
holder.tvCustomerContactNo.setText("" + details.getPrimaryContactNo());
holder.tvProductWeight.setText("" + details.getProductWeight());
holder.tvCustomerStatus.setText("" + details.getCustomerStatus());
holder.tvDeliveryManStatus.setText("" + details.getDeliveryManStatus());
holder.tvAddress.setText("" + details.getAddress());
holder.tvDeliveryMan.setText("" + details.getCustomerName() + " ( " + details.getPrimaryContactNo() + " ) ");
holder.tvTime.setText("" + details.getTime());
holder.tvPickUpDate.setText("" + details.getPickupDate());

holder.tvDeliveryCharge.setText("" + details.getDeliveryCharge());


//Opening DialogFragment on Click Listner

  holder.tvDeliveryMan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) (context);

        android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        android.app.Fragment prev = activity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dvdialog");

        if (prev != null) {
            ft.remove(prev);
        }
        ft.addToBackStack(null);

        DeliveryManDetailsDialog newFragment = new DeliveryManDetailsDialog();
        newFragment.show(ft, "dvdialog");

    }
});

holder.tvAddress.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;


        //Address icon click listner right side

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (event.getRawX() >= (holder.tvAddress.getRight() - holder.tvAddress.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {

                // your action here
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, RouteActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("custLat", details.getCustLatitude());
                intent.putExtra("custLong", details.getCustLongitude());
                intent.putExtra("boLat", details.getBoLatitude());
                intent.putExtra("boLong", details.getBosLongitude());

                context.startActivity(intent);


            }


            return true;

        }
        return true;
    }
});


}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
return list.size();
}

public void registerExpand(int position, ViewHolder holder) {

if (mExpandedPositionSet.contains(position)) {

    //Replacing views at runtime and arrow animation

    ViewGroupUtils.replaceView(holder.timeLayout, holder.statusLayout);


holder.orderbox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.box_fill_drawable);
    holder.ivArrow.animate().rotation(360).start();
    removeExpand(position);




} else {
    ViewGroupUtils.replaceView(holder.statusLayout, holder.timeLayout);

    holder.orderbox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.box_fill_drawable_top);
    holder.ivArrow.animate().rotation(180).start();
    addExpand(position);


}
}

public void removeExpand(int position) {


mExpandedPositionSet.remove(position);


}

public void addExpand(int position) {


mExpandedPositionSet.add(position);

}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
public ExpandableLayout expandableLayout;
public LinearLayout orderbox, orderbox_bottom;
public ImageView ivArrow;
public TextView tvAddress, tvOrderNo, tvCustomerName, tvTotalPrice, tvCustomerContactNo;
public TextView tvProductWeight, tvCustomerStatus, tvDeliveryManStatus;
public TextView tvDeliveryCharge, tvDeliveryMan, tvTime;
public TextView tvPickUpDate;
public LinearLayout statusLayout, statusParentLayout, timeLayout, timeParentLayout, addressLayout;


public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    expandableLayout = (ExpandableLayout) 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.expandable_layout);
    orderbox = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderbox);

    orderbox_bottom = (LinearLayout) 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderbox_bottom);
    ivArrow = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivArrow);

    tvOrderNo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvOrderNo);
    tvCustomerName = (TextView) 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCustomerName);
    tvTotalPrice = (TextView) 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTotalPrice);
    tvCustomerContactNo = (TextView) 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCustomerContactNo);
    tvProductWeight = (TextView) 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductWeight);
    tvCustomerStatus = (TextView) 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCustomerStatus);
    tvDeliveryManStatus = (TextView) 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDeliveryManStatus);
    tvDeliveryCharge = (TextView) 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDeliveryCharge);
    tvAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAddress);
    tvDeliveryMan = (TextView) 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDeliveryMan);
    tvTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
    tvPickUpDate = (TextView) 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPickUpDate);

    statusParentLayout = (LinearLayout) 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.statusParentLayout);
    statusLayout = (LinearLayout) 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.statusLayout);
    timeParentLayout = (LinearLayout) 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeParentLayout);
    timeLayout = (LinearLayout) 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeDateLayout);
    addressLayout = (LinearLayout) 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.addressLayout);
}

public void updateItem(final int position, final ViewHolder holder) {
    holder.orderbox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.box_fill_drawable_top);
    holder.expandableLayout.setOnExpandListener(new ExpandableLayout.OnExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public void onExpand(boolean expanded) {

            registerExpand(position, holder);

        }
    });

    expandableLayout.setExpand(mExpandedPositionSet.contains(position));

}
}
```

**Calling Adapter from Fragment**

```
**  PendingOrdersAdapter adapter = new PendingOrdersAdapter(getActivity(), detailsArrayList);

    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
    recyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

recyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
    recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();**
```

[image: Expanded recycleview itemView]

Comment: how many records you are getting from your web service?

Comment: 18 JSON objects (It can be more ) . Each object has 43 values

Answer (score 0):

Make one class, for example, Util and added this method to the class and use it.

```
 public static void setDivider(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager) {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
            recyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            recyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
            DividerItemDecoration horizontalDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
            Drawable horizontalDivider = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.horizontal_divider);
            horizontalDecoration.setDrawable(horizontalDivider);
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(horizontalDecoration);
        }
```

here first parameter is `context`, second one pass your `recyclerview` and third one pass the layout manager.
if you have more stuff then change the `CacheSize`

Comment: Is their any effect of Divider Item Decoration ?

Comment: DividerItemDecoration for the give simple line after every cell of the recyclerview

Comment: Above solution only work if you refer all the best practices for the recycler view, for example, CustomerDetails cd = list.get(position); then after user cd.getOrderId()

Comment: for more information, you can refer this link 
https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview

Comment: @HarshBhavsar above answer is valid because your cache temporary bases stored for the scrolling efficeny.

Comment: You can see my adapter code i think its from best practices

Comment: add fragment second time then recyclerview lagging. some of the device. please check my question any help very appreciated.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60880908/add-same-fragment-second-time-then-recyclerview-scroll-lagginghang

Answer (score 0):

use this 
`recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`